# I get the error "rspec: command not found" but 'gem list' shows rspec installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I'm currently in the directory of an app I'm working on. I think I have rspec installed because when I type:

```
gem list
```

I get the following

```
...
some_gem
rspec (1.3.2)
rspec-rails (1.3.4)
another_gem 
...
```

But when I type

```
rspec ./spec/my_favorite_test_spec.rb
```

I get the error

```
-bash: rspec: command not found
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

RSpec 1.x uses the `spec` executable. RSpec 2.x uses `rspec`.